# Need help in Identifying this succulent and taking care of it

Tags: identification, plant-care, indoors, watering, succulents

I was gifted this succulent plant about 10 days back.
Need help in identifying the exact species of the plant.
I live in Bangalore, India. If it helps.

I searched online and found it to look similar to Sunburst (aeonium davidbramwellii).
But the color and pattern of the leaves do not match.

[image: Succulent Plant Pic 1]

[image: Succulent Plant Pic 2]

Have watered it twice since, lightly, keeping the soil little moist after watering.
I could see couple of brown leaves on the bottom part, is this normal or is the watering not being done properly?

[image: Succulent Plant, Brown Leaves]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an echeveria, probably the flat leaf echeveria. Don't water too often, as the plant also stores water in the leaves. Watering once in 10-12 days should be fine. Make sure there are holes at the bottom of the pot, so excess water can drain out. You should be adding enough water so that it drains from the bottom of the pot.

Keep the plant indoors. Brown leaves on the bottom are normal. These leaves are dying, so pull them gently and if it comes out easily, remove it from the plant.

Comment: Thank you. Yup it looks like it's one of the flat leaf variety. I was using a spray bottle to water it, will resort to watering it thoroughly till it drains out. Pulled the brown leaves gently and it did break away easily.